# Is there any difference between prisoner.iana.org, blackhole-1.iana.org, and blackhole-2.iana.org?

Tags: domain-name-system, tcpip, blackhole, rfc

Probably not the most useful question, but I'm curious:

I understand (in theory) that if a reverse lookup for a private IP makes it makes it past your own DNS servers you should get back "prisoner.iana.org" "blackhole-1.iana.org" or "blackhole-2.iana.org" I don't understand why there's more than one however. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blackhole servers contain DNS zones for the 10.in-addr.arpa, 16.172.in-addr.arpa, and
168.192.in-addr.arpa ranges, so cover all private IP addresses. prisoner.iana.org is the primary DNS server for those zones, the other 2 are secondary servers, used for backup and for when the primary server is to busy.

Comment: Only very partially true. The biggest error is the last sentence. Authoritative name servers (primary or secondaries) are used all the time, however busy they are. The DNS client does not know what is the primary and what are the secondaries. Also, prisoner.iana.org is NOT in the list of NS and thereforewill NOT receive queries at all (it is there only to absorb DNS updates).

Answer (score 2):

The `blackhole-[12].iana.org` servers are part of a DNS Anycast cloud operated by  [AS112](http://public.as112.net/) designed to soak up `PTR` record queries for the RFC 1918 private network address space and the `169.254/16` autoconfiguration block.

This was done to mitigate the traffic that these useless queries were inflicting on the DNS root name servers.

All such `PTR` queries to the name servers return `NXDOMAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard for the DNS, [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) says (section 4.1) that, for reliability reasons, **every** DNS zone must have at least two name servers. This apply also to the "reverse" zones such as 10.in-addr.arpa and so on.